# My obstacle avoiding car doesn't work with dry cells

Tags: arduino, motor, robot, battery, gearing

Ok, I am not a genius in such projects but, it is the first project I am doing in robotics.
The problem is that the wheels of the car doesn't continuously tend to rotate when I power the motor driver with the dry cell but if I power the Arduino with the cable and connect it into my laptop then it seems to rotate perfectly fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what dry cell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you are not delivering enough Power (Watts) to the motors when using a battery. This could mean not enough Voltage and/or not enough Current.

It is a common difficulty for a battery's voltage to decrease when under load, so you need to measure it while the motors are running.